# Can't filter my employers in a Django project

Tags: python, django

So, I have a Django website, where I have companies with "pages".~
I need to add some employers to that page, but before I add them, I need to check if there is a page created, and then if there are some employers already in that company and I want my result to be "dynamic", so here is how I tried to achieve this:

That's my employer module:

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    funcion = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.png")
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My company model which is the "father"

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.png")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False)
    logo = models.ImageField(default="default.png")
    welcome = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, default="Welcome", max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
```

and here is my view, where im getting errors because i dont know how to achieve what i want

```
@login_required
def listing_employer(request):
    try:
        company = Company.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except company.DoesNotExist:
        company = None
    
    employers = Employer.objects.filter(company=company)
    context = {
        "employers": employers,
        "company": company,

    }
    return render (request, "list_employer.html", context)
```

and here is my HTML-django where im trying to set all the verifications but there's always a problem with values on my variables:

```
{% if company %}
  {% for employer in employers %}
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div class="member d-flex align-items-start">
        <div class="pic"><img src="{{ employer.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="height: 150px; width: 150px"></div>
        <div class="member-info">
            <h4>{{ employer.name }}</h4>
            <span>{{ employer.funcion }}</span>
            <div class="social">
            <a href="{{ employer.facebook }}"><i class="ri-facebook-fill"></i></a>
            <a href="{{ employer.instagram }}"><i class="ri-instagram-fill"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/employers/{{ employer.id }}/update/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar</button></a>
        <a href="/employers/{{ employer.id }}/delete/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
      </div>
      
  {% empty %}
      <h1>Nao tem empregados ainda ...</h1>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <a href=" {% url 'create-employer' %} "><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Empregado</button></a>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <a href=" {% url 'create-employer' %} "><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Empregado</button></a>
  </div>
{% else %}
<h1>E necessario ter uma pagina para adicionar empregados</h1>
<a href="/companies/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">A minha pagina</button></a>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: It likes like an OK approach.  Can you share the errors so we can see what is causing them.

Comment: There is too many types of error, ive tried to instanciate de company variable as empty string, as None, as everything, but the erro thats giving me with that code, is :UnboundLocalError at /employers/
local variable 'company' referenced before assignmentt'

Comment: Telling us the errors will help us fix them!  This line "except company.DoesNotExist" should be "except Company.DoesNotExist".